# SPARK: Load master's directory on slave

Tags: scala, apache-spark, directory

I would like to read an entire master's directory, on slaves.

I know that, I can use sc.addFile and SparkFiles.get to read master's files on slaves.

**Questions:**

1) Is there the same for directory ?

2) If not, is it possible to run functions on all the slaves of my cluster ?

Comment: what do you mean by master's directory? zip your directory and add as file to sparkFiles.

Comment: I mean: read a directory only present on the master machine. But in fact, it's also ok, if you know a way to spread this directory on every slaves.